# Convert struct to matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, struct, matlab-struct

Is there a way to convert a struct (2 fields with 52 variables each) to a matrix (2x52)? Thank you

```
struct:

    sym (1x53)
    prob (1x53)
```

I have tried the following which gives me a 1 x 1 cell array

```
symProb = reshape({x.sym}, size(53));
```

I have also tried `struct2cell` which does the same.

Comment: Can you provide actual example of you struct with those variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing (since it's only two fields), is to simply concatenate them along the first dimension using `cat`

```
result = cat(1, x.sym, x.prob);
```

Or you could just use `[]` and `;`

```
result = [x.sym; x.prob]
```

If you want a more general solution, you could use `struct2array` with some reshaping

```
result = reshape(struct2array(x), [], numel(x)).';
```

Note that all of this assumes that the data within `sym` and `prob` are actually the same datatype and therefore able to be placed within the same array, otherwise a cell array is the only way to hold both fields.

Also your code is yielding a 1 x 1 cell array because you're wrapping your data `x.sym` *inside* of a `1 x 1` cell array.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is as follows:

```
symVec = [x.sym(:)]
probVec = [x.prob(:)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
cell2mat(struct2cell(YourStructure))
```